# How to detect Application Launch

Tags: android

Can someone give the explaination about this question that how this detected application launch by catching startapplication calls in the launcher in the following question?

[Detecting android Activity launches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034801/detecting-android-activity-launches)

Some code would be highly appreciated. I have tried the first two options but having the same problems. Kindly Help

**Details:**

I need to detect Application Launch in Android. That whenever any application is opened, my application should be triggered. This is very similar to what App Locking applications do.

I have written the following code in a service to get the currently running application:

```
ActivityManager mngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = mngr.getRunningTasks(2);
String CurrApp = taskList.get(0).baseActivity.getPackageName();
```

The problem is that I need to detect whenever there is new application in `tasklist` i.e. when user opens any application.

Possible solutions and there drawbacks are given in the question that I posted. In this question, the perfect solution is to catch the `startapplication` calls in the launcher. I need to know how to do it.

Comment: What are your problems?

Comment: I have put some details below